# Keras flow_from_directory shuffle not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am loading data using Keras `flow_from_directory` and i have set `shuffle=True`, but when I print `train_generator.classes`, it does not return me shuffle classes. It returns all classes in order in following way

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4,
       4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32)
```

SO what is the proper way to shuffle images, after being loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

train_generator.classes gives the class assigned to each sample based on the sorted order of folder names. **They are not shuffled at this point.**

The samples are shuffled within the batch generator so that **when a batch is requested by the fit_generator or evaluate_generator then the random samples are given.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i get labels out of this, actually i am trying to get label.
if i try `y_true=val_generator.next()[1]` i get the label equal to batch size, but i want all `val_generator` labels

Comment: You can set Shuffle = True for Train and Shuffle = False for Validation set. Get the `y_pred = numpy.rint(predictions)` from model predictions and get true labels by `y_true = validation_generator.classes` and finally `print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))`